# data binding in AOS - possible?

Tags: angular, animation, aos.js

I'm using Animate On Scroll in my angular poject, I have a bunch of images, that I want to reveal one after the other.

```html
 <div class="img-gallery">
        <div *ngFor="let imgSrc of images" data-aos="zoom-in">
            <img [src]="imgSrc">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I wanted to add th each wrapper div the `data-aos-delay` directive, like this

```html
<div *ngFor="let imgSrc of images; let i = index" data-aos="zoom-in" [data-aos-delay]="i * 100">
    <img [src]="imgSrc">
</div>
```

but, expectedly - it shows me the error

> Can't bind to 'data-aos-delay' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

How can I implement it anyhow? any implementation will be accepted gratefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change it to below

You also have a typo on `index`

```
<div *ngFor="let imgSrc of images; let i = index" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="{{i * 100}}">
    <img [src]="imgSrc">
</div>
```

You can also do like this

```
<div *ngFor="let imgSrc of images; let i = index" data-aos="zoom-in" [attr.data-aos-delay]="i * 100">
    <img [src]="imgSrc">
</div>
```

Comment: the typo was in the question only, I fixed it. Your first answer showed an error as well, but the second answer solved the problme, thanks!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I marked the answer as helpfull when the system let me to..